# Scroll bar for child of parent with percentage max height when child's height is unknown upfront

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple pop-up dialog. Parent should have `max-height: 90%`. Parent has two children. First one is a title with `min-height: Xpx` and second is content which should fill the rest of the space (height). How do I describe rules for limiting content's height so that content would have scroll bar?

```
.parent {
    max-height: 90%;
}

.title {
    min-height: Xpx; /* title should be able to grow when needed*/
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="title">

    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about adding a code snippet so that we can see it for ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using flexbox.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; //set directon top to bottom
}

.content {
  flex: 1; //Takes up remaining space
  overflow: auto; //show scrollbar when content is overflowing
}
```

And dont forget the vendor prefixes.

Comment: So far these rules give me a desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are very close already. There is a property that makes it easy for you to achieve your content's height. Just set height as -webkit-fill-available. This should help:

```
.parent {
    max-height: 90%;
}

.title {
    min-height: Xpx; /* title should be able to grow when needed*/
}

.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `-webkit-fill-available` property made scroll bar visible however I was unable to scroll all the way to the end of `content`. It's probably because of some other CSS properties that I have defined... Also I think webkit is not supported on all major browsers https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Applications%20using%20WebKit